# Harmonica help please

Tags: harmonica

I am unsure of what harmonica key is played, I think I am playing the right harmonica and I can get the first note and some others but I can’t seem to get all. Maybe I’m using the wrong one?
The harmonica is used on the intro but. The guitar is standard tuning, with capo on 2. The intro is G, B7, Em, - C, B7, Em.

Answer (score 2):

Song starts with an open G chord on guitar, 2nd fret capo. So it's a concert A major. On standard, you'd use a harp in that same key - A. But here, it's played cross-harp, so a harp a P4th higher is used. That makes it a harp in D major.

There are minor harps, but I think that will do the job.